# Convert date with format dd.mm.yy to yyyy-mm-dd in python

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime-format

I have a date with format:

```
    d1 = "22.05.15"
```

I want to change to date with format:

```
    d1 = "2015-05-22"
```

I tried converting using datetime:

```
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d1,'%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```

But, it does not work because datetime does not support date with format '22.05.15' but only '22.05.2015'

Is there any way out to convert date of such format ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `%y` instead of `%Y`:

```
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1,'%d.%m.%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
>>> d2
'2015-05-22'
```

Comment: that works. Thank you. I was not aware of significance of small 'y' and caps lock Y.

Comment: Can we also try it on list of 10000+ dates ? actually i tried but it slow down